# Problem when add sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv in MAMP

Tags: php, sql-server, mamp

Here I want to add sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv in MAMP. I want to download and install the package with pecl, running this command:

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

But i got error:

> Could not download from
>   "http://pecl.php.net/get/pdo_sqlsrv-5.3.0.tgz", cannot download
>   "pecl/pdo_sqlsrv" (File
>   http://pecl.php.net:80/get/pdo_sqlsrv-5.3.0.tgz not valid (received:
>   HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable )) Error: cannot download
>   "pecl/pdo_sqlsrv" Could not download from
>   "http://pecl.php.net/get/sqlsrv-5.3.0.tgz", cannot download
>   "pecl/sqlsrv" (File http://pecl.php.net:80/get/sqlsrv-5.3.0.tgz not
>   valid (received: HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable )) Error: cannot
>   download "pecl/sqlsrv" Download failed install failed

I tried to download the package directly from http://pecl.php.net/get/pdo_sqlsrv-5.3.0.tz but just don't know where or how to generate `.so` files. I'm really new to Mac. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39889897/php-7-x-connection-with-mssql-server-with-mamp

Comment: Still stuck right now @TahaPaksu

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/mac/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still have this problem:

Replace

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

With

```
sudo /pathtoyourmamp/php/bin/pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

Edit php.ini:

```
extension=sqlsrv
extension=pdo_sqlsrv
```